# Facing issue in elasticsearch mapping of nutch crawled document

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

Facing some serious issues while using nutch and elasticsearch for crawling purpose.

We have two data storage engines in our App.

1. MySql
2. Elasticsearch

Lets say I have 10 urls   stored in urls table of mysql db. Now I want to fetch these urls from table in run time and write these into seed,txt for crawling. I have written all these urls into need,txt at one go. Now my crawling starts and then I index these docs inside elasticsearch in an index(lets say url index).  But I want to maintain a reference  inside elasticsearch index  so that I can fetch a particular url's crawled details for analytics purpose as elasticsearch index only contains crawled data.  For ex.

My table structure in mysql is :

Table Url:

id  url

---

1  www.google.com

Elasticsearch index mapping I want is :

Index  url:

{
_id: "www.google.com",
type: "doc",
content : "Hello world"
url_id : 1 ,
.
.
.
}

Here url_id is the field value of id column of the crawled url inside urls table.

I can create separate index for each url but that solution is not ideal because at the end of day I will be having multiple indices. So how to achieve this after crawling.  Do I have to modify the elastic search indexer. I am using nutch 1.12 and elastichsearch 1.7.1 .Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the url_id as an additional metadata in your seed list and use the urlmeta and index-metadata plugins so that the Key/Value gets passed to the outlinks (if necessary) or at least be available for the indexing.

See [Nutch WIKI](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags) for an explanation of how to index metatags.

Comment: Thanks a ton man.  I passed url_id along with url and used urlmeta plugin. FInally this url creates url_id  field in elasticsearch after indexing. Now I can map my url table in mysql table to elasticsearch index. This saved a lot of time mine.

Comment: @user2354150 you still haven't marked my answer above as accepted. Probably best to open a new question, will make it easier for others to find it