# Pass metadata along seed urls with Nutch 1.X REST APi

Tags: nutch

I'm currently trying to include the seed url in the data indexed for each url in my search backend (currently ElasticSearch).

I've seen in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697398/facing-issue-in-elasticsearch-mapping-of-nutch-crawled-document) that metadata could be passed with each seed, which could suit my need. However, I'm using the REST API to [create my seed list](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI#Seed_List_creation), and it seems that metadata aren't allowed in the `seedUrls` parameter.

Has anybody tried to do this with the REST API?

Is there another way to achieve this?
I thought I could write a custom IndexingFilter to add the seed URL in the NutchDocument to be indexed, but at this point, the seed URL is not available from what I've seen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the REST API doesn't seem to support handling associated metadata. I believe that this doens't require such a great effort to accomplish, basically we just need to handle the JSON payload and customize the corresponding entity `SeedUrl` to hold the metadata and of course customize the [`writeToSeedFile`](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/service/resources/SeedResource.java#L92) method.

Although your approach of writing an `IndexingFilter` wouldn't work. The seed URLs are injected at the very begining of the crawl life cycle, and the `IndexingFilter` are only responsable of choosing what gets indexed into your storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi @ThomasC take a look at https://github.com/jorgelbg/nutch/tree/NUTCH-2353 and the associated issue on JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2353 basically the way to add metadata to the seed file now wille be with a request like the example showed on the JIRA issue.

Comment: Thanks Jorge for this great addition! My workaround has been to create the seedfile myself instead of using REST API, but this will be easier and more consistent.

Comment: No problem, I've submitted a PR for review and will be merging the PR into master in the following days.